# Function doesn't wait for nested function before returning

Tags: ios, swift

I have a closure to retrieve a token string:

```
var getAccessToken = { () -> (String) in
    var token = String("")
    credentialsManager.credentials(minTTL: 60) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let credentials):
            token = credentials.accessToken         
        case .failure(let error):
            token = ""
        }
    }
  return token
}
```

When I call `getAccessToken()` from another function like below, it always returns empty, as it doesn't wait for `credentialsManager.credentials` closure to return:

```
    func getUserProfile(completion: @escaping (UserProfile) -> ()) {
                                      
        let accessToken = getAccessToken()
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://asdf.com")!

        enum DataTaskError: Error {
          case invalidResponse, rateLimited, serverBusy
        }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
 
        request.addValue("Bearer \(accessToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
 
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, _, _) in
         
            guard let data = data else { return }
            
            do {
                let userProfile = try JSONDecoder().decode(UserProfile.self, from: data)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(userProfile)
                }
                
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
           
        }
        .resume()
    }
```

I tried using a completion handler with `getAccessToken`:

```
func getAccessToken(completion: @escaping () -> (String)) { 
   //...
   completion(token)
}
```

but Swift errored: `Argument passed to call that takes no arguments`

Comment: You need to change our nested function accept a completion handler and return `Void`, for example `var getAccessToken = { (_ then: @escaping (String) -> ()) -> Void in ... }`, then when you want to return the token you would use `then(credentials.accessToken)` - the function CAN NOT return a value, as the result won't be known until some point in the future

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks, though Swift erroring with `Missing argument for parameter #1 in call` when calling `let accessToken = getAccessToken()`

Comment: You now need to call it so that it will accept a compiletion block, it will NOT return you the value via the function call, but instead, will pass the value to you completion block, `getAccessToken { token in ... }`

Comment: `URLSession.shared.dataTask` is a bad ground task, it's executing in a different thread, thus the reason for the completion blocks

Answer (score 2):

You return the token before the *credentialsManager.credentials* generate the token in the first case. Second case your completion handler syntax is wrong for this scenario. Use the proper completion handler as below.

```
// completion will return the token, if credentialsManager is able created the token successfully
// in any case credentialsManager failed to generate the token it will return the underlying error

   func getAccessToken(completion: @escaping (Result<String,Error>) -> Void) {
        credentialsManager.credentials(minTTL: 60) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let credentials):
                completion(.success(credentials.accessToken))
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }
    
    func getUserProfile(completion: @escaping (UserProfile) -> ()) {
        
        getAccessToken { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let token):
                // What ever you do with token
                // here
                
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                // Handle error case
                break
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: While I see this as a potential good answer, please add some kind of explanation as to what is being done. It helps, otherwise an answer like this just encourages copy/paste without trying to understand what the code is doing.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using `DataTaskError` in your function. Given that, there is no reason to use a `do/catch`.

```swift
var userProfile: UserProfile {
  get async throws {
    let userProfile = try JSONDecoder().decode(
      UserProfile.self,
      from: await URLSession.shared.data(
        for: {
          var request = URLRequest(url: .init(string: "https://asdf.com")!)
          [ ("Bearer \(getAccessToken())", "Authorization"),
            ("application/json", "Content-Type")
          ].forEach {
            request.addValue($0, forHTTPHeaderField: $1)
          }
          return request
        } ()
      ).0
    )

    return await MainActor.run { userProfile }
  }
}
```